# Parsing XML JAXB - Throwing parse error

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am working on parsing a large xml file using StAX and JAXB, and I am getting this error:

`com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().`

The code for this is:

```
public class UnmarshalDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(xmlpath);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.nextTag();

        while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("Name")) { //until tag is name
            xsr.nextTag(); //get next tag
        }

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Name.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Name> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Name.class);
        xsr.close();

        Name name = jb.getValue();

        System.out.println("First Name: "+ name.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Middle Initial: " + name.getMiddleInitial());
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + name.getLastName());
    }
}
```

The object class is:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Name {

    String FirstName;
    String MiddleInitial;
    String LastName;

    public Name() {}

    public Name(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName) {
        super();
        FirstName = firstName;
        MiddleInitial = middleInitial;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleInitial() {
        return MiddleInitial;
    }

    public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial) {
        MiddleInitial = middleInitial;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [FirstName=" + FirstName + ", MiddleInitial=" + MiddleInitial + ", LastName=" + LastName + "]";
    }

}
```

The beginning of the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
        <xfa:data>
            <FormData>
                <Application>
                    <AppType>
                        <Income>1</Income>
                            <Option>0</Option>
```

The Income element is the failing line.

And the error I am receiving is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().at [row,col,system-id]: [7,38, "xmlfilepath"]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:621)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:491)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:475)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1224)
    at com.nm.ni.workflow.service.UnmarshalDemo.main(UnmarshalDemo.java:35)
```

I am confused as to the source of the error as the code is able to parse simple sample xml such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns0:findCustomerResponse xmlns:ns0="http://service.jaxws.blog/">
            <InsuredData>
                <Name>
                    <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
                    <MiddleInitial>M</MiddleInitial>
                    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                </Name>
            </InsuredData>
</ns0:findCustomerResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

with a console print out of:

```
First Name: Jane
Middle Initial: M
Last Name: Doe
```

but when it gets to more complex xml it results in an exception.

My question is why am I getting this exception and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: What XML input produces the error?

Comment: Your XML file may be large, but the error is reported as being in column 38 of line 7, so can you at least update your post with the start of that file, including the "failing" line? Might you have some (possibly invisible) invalid characters in your  file? (i.e. Not text and not whitespace)

Comment: I entered the first part of the xml file including the line failing line

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for [XMLStreamReader#nextTag()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#nextTag--):

> Skips any white space (isWhiteSpace() returns true), COMMENT, or
>   PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION, until a START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT is
>   reached. **If other than white space characters, COMMENT,
>   PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION, START_ELEMENT, END_ELEMENT are encountered, an
>   exception is thrown.** This method should be used when processing
>   element-only content seperated by white space.

I think it's obvious what you should do: Use `next()` and `isStartElement()` combined in your loop test.

Comment: How would that code change help? The existing code works for simple files, the **WstxParsingException** suggests that the issue is with the XML file (XAF data) being processed, and the specification you linked to shows that **nextTag()** is essentially a special case of what **next()** is doing anyway. And both **next()** and **nextTag()** will throw an XMLStreamException for illegal or unexpected data. Isn't the real solution to correct the data in the file being processed, or am I completely misunderstanding/misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: `nextTag()` does not work when there's non-white space characters between tags (elements). The sample data has `<Income>1</Income>` at line 7, i.e. `non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS`.

Comment: OK, but if _"`nextTag()` does not work when there's non-white space characters between tags"_ (e.g. for _"Income"_), why does it work when reading the small XML file listed in the OP which also contains non-white space characters between tags (e.g. for _"MiddleInitial"_)? I ran the OP code against that small XML file, and it really does produce the console output as shown.

Comment: In the working example, the XmlStreamReader is handed over to the JAXB unmarshaller before encountering any non-white space characters.